# ANTLR4: Token rewritter -- compacting space around a delete

Tags: antlr4

I have the following example grammar:

```
start: (comments | removes)*
comments: COMMENT;
removes: REMOVE_ME;


COMMENT: ';'~('\n'|'\r')*;
REMOVE_ME: 'remove_me';
fragment NEW_LINE: (('\n')
                  |('\r')
                  |('\r\n'));
NEW_LINES: NEW_LINE+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
OTHER: . -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I have the following example text

```
; comments here
; please come closer comment!


remove_me


remove_me

; comment
```

When I visit each rule I can use the token rewriter to remove a token

```
    rewritter.delete(ctx.REMOVE_ME);
```

However what I would like to do is, cleanup the empty new lines prior to REMOVE_ME and end up with text like the following.

```
; comments here
; please come closer comment!
; comment
```

How can I ask the rewriter to remove previous new lines until another construct or the beginning of the file is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
My first attempt to solve this problem was to change the grammar. The fact is that the grammar tends to ignore the carriage return characters and space chars.

I use your grammar:

```
grammar Toek;

start: (comments|removes)*;
comments: COMMENT;
removes: REMOVE_ME;

COMMENT: ';'~('\n'|'\r')*;
REMOVE_ME: 'remove_me';

fragment NEW_LINE: (('\n')
                  |('\r')
                  |('\r\n'));
NEW_LINES: NEW_LINE+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
OTHER: . -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Then I wrote a simple JUNIT test to parse a string (the one you wrote) and I apply my solution. The solution is based on Function Programming (it's only to simplify the code, it is not necessary). When the ANTLR finish replacing the rule you specified, I take the obtained string, I split it into lines and I remove all the lines empty.

The test (JUNIT) and some needed class:

```java
@Test
public void testOK() throws Throwable {
        final String text = "; comments here\n" +
                "; please come closer comment!" + 
                "\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "remove_me" + 
                "\n"+
                "\n" + 
                "remove_me" + 
                "\n" + 
                "; comment";
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        List<Triple<Token, Token, String>> replace = new ArrayList<>();     
        ToekBaseListener listener = new ToekBaseListener() {

            @Override
            public void enterRemoves(RemovesContext ctx) {
                System.out.println("-: [" + ctx.getText() + "]");
                replace.add(new Pair<Token, Token,>(ctx.start, ctx.stop));
            }
        };

        ToekLexer lexer = new ToekLexer(CharStreams.fromString(text));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ToekParser parser = new ToekParser(tokens);

        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.addErrorListener(new JQLBaseErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line,
                    int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("unespected char at pos %s of text '%s'", charPositionInLine, text));
            }
        });
        ParserRuleContext context = parser.start();

        walker.walk(listener, context);
        TokenStreamRewriter rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokens);

        for (Triple<Token, Token, String> item : replace) {
            rewriter.replace(item.value0, item.value1, "");
        }

        String solution=split(rewriter.getText());
        System.out.println(solution);
    }

...
public class Pair {
    public Pair(double k ,double v) {
       key=k;
       value=v;
    }

    private String key;
    private String value;  

    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

And the method responsible of solution. Some explanation: take the string, convert in a stream (splitting by '\n'), filter only element that has a size >0, recompact all together.

```java
public static String removeBlankLines(String str) {
  return Stream.of(str.split("\n"))
         .filter(elem -> elem!=null && elem.trim().length()>0)              
         .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

The output is like you want:

```
; comments here
; please come closer comment!
; comment
```

Comment: Okay I understand so the solution is to not use a token rewriter to do all the work. It is the combination of a rewriter and manual text processing which can achieve the end result.